# Added Meteor Package to C: by mistake

Tags: meteor, package

I'm new to meteor: I have mistakenly added a package by entering the below line in command prompt:

```
C:\meteor add 'package name'
```

(instead of entering the command within the project directory). The command prompt seemed to show that it was loading and there was no error. Was there anything created? How do I undo this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add Meteor packages in folders containing a Meteor application. 
In fact, if you try to `meteor add` something in a non-Meteor folder you will get the following error:

> add: You're not in a Meteor project directory.

So, if you successfully add a Meteor package in c: it may imply that you previously created a Meteor application in this folder. 
You can check if this is the case by looking for a '.meteor' folder in c: (c:.meteor). 
If there is one you can remove this folder safely as Meteor installation folder is located in `c:\Users\your_name\AppDate\Local\.meteor`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you entered a real package name instead of `'package name` you can remove it just by entering `meteor remove 'package name'`